# Dataset contains a definition for the field, the filed is missing from returned result

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reporting-services, dataset

When I run SSRS, to view the table, one filed is missing data and blank,  I see the following message :

Warning [rsMissingFieldInDataSet] The dataset 'ds_GLDetail' contains a definition for the Field 'Associated_Invoice_Description'. This field is missing from the returned result set from the data source.

Warning [rsErrorReadingDataSetField] The dataset 'ds_GLDetail' contains a definition for the Field 'Associated_Invoice_Description'. The data extension returned an error during reading the field. There is no data for the field at position 10.

I am using Visual Studio to editing SSRS report.

I have inserted two new fields,

one is customer name

one is invoice description.

My SQL query is running correctly in sql server.  The query can show the whole data.

Can someone advise how I should work on it ?

```
SELECT
GLD.PA_gldetailId AS 'GL Detail Transaction GUID',
GLD.PA_transactiondate AS 'GL Detail Transaction Date',
GLD.PA_batchnumber AS 'GL Detail Transaction Batch Number',
GLDCoA.PA_AccountNumber As 'GL Detail Transaction Target GL',
GLD.PA_amountdebit AS 'GL Detail Transaction Debit',
GLD.PA_amountcredit AS 'GL Detail Transaction Credit',
I.InvoiceNumber AS 'Associated Invoice Number',
I.PA_InvoiceDate AS 'Associated Invoice Date',
I.CustomeridName AS 'Assocoated Invoice Customer',
Invde.Description AS 'Asscoiated Invoice Description',
I.TotalLineItemAmount 'Associated Invoice Current Net',
I.TotalTax AS 'Associated Invoice Current Tax',
I.TotalAmount AS 'Associated Invoice Current Gross'
FROM
PA_gldetail AS GLD
LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice AS I ON I.InvoiceId = GLD.pa_invoiceid
LEFT OUTER JOIN PA_ChartofAccounts AS GLDCoA ON GLD.pa_glaccountid = GLDCoA.PA_ChartofAccountsId
LEFT OUTER JOIN InvoiceDetail AS Invde ON Invde.InvoiceId = GLD.pa_invoiceid
WHERE
YEAR(GLD.PA_transactiondate) = @param_Year
AND MONTH(GLD.PA_transactiondate) = @param_Month
ORDER BY
3 ASC, 2 ASC, 4 ASC
```

```
SELECT
DISTINCT YEAR(pa_transactiondate) AS Year
FROM
PA_GLDetail
WHERE
StateCode = 0
ORDER BY
1 ASC
```

```
SELECT
DISTINCT MONTH(pa_transactiondate) AS MonthValue,
CASE
WHEN MONTH(pa_transactiondate) = 1 THEN 'January'
WHEN MONTH(pa_transactiondate)= 2 THEN 'February'
WHEN MONTH(pa_transactiondate)= 3 THEN 'March'
WHEN MONTH(pa_transactiondate)= 4 THEN 'April'
WHEN MONTH(pa_transactiondate)= 5 THEN 'May'
WHEN MONTH(pa_transactiondate)= 6 THEN 'June'
WHEN MONTH(pa_transactiondate)= 7 THEN 'July'
WHEN MONTH(pa_transactiondate)= 8 THEN 'August'
WHEN MONTH(pa_transactiondate)= 9 THEN 'September'
WHEN MONTH(pa_transactiondate)= 10 THEN 'October'
WHEN MONTH(pa_transactiondate)= 11 THEN 'November'
WHEN MONTH(pa_transactiondate)= 12 THEN 'December'
ELSE 'ERROR'
END AS MonthLabel
FROM
PA_GLDetail
WHERE
StateCode = 0
AND YEAR(pa_transactiondate) = @param_Year
ORDER BY
1 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Double-click you dataset in the "Report Data" panel then click refresh fields. Is sounds like the dataset query has been updated but the fields have not been refresh to show the changes.

Comment: Hi Alan, I did try that.  when I click datasets in report data panel,  and check datasets properties , it shows refresh fields in Query section, and I did refresh fields. The issue is still happening.   I am able to see data with new inserted field customer,  but I cannot see it for new inserted description.   Can you help here ?  Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi Alan,  I just noticed that,  when I click refresh,  my report cannot show now.  An error happened.  it said " the value expression for the text box 'toolbox98' refers to the filed' associated_invoice_description". Report item expressions can only refer to fileds within the current datasets scope or, if inside an aggregate , the specified datasets scope. letters in the names of fields must use the correct case."    is this meaning my current data set do not have the field of description ?

Comment: @Darren2020 looks like the column names have been changed. The fields within SSRS are case sensitive. If you look at error message, is says "associated_invoice_description" is missing.. yet your colum name in your select  is camel case

Comment: Thank You.  I noticed that my filed name is error typo.  Thanks